# Insert a new record in a many to many relation using EF6 and WinForm

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, insert-update

In my case I have a `WinForm` project and a Server (using EF). There are two entity (`Doctor` & `Clinic`) that have a many-to-many relation Like :

```
 public class Doctor
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Clinic> clinics { get; set; }
    // And some others
}

public class Clinic
    {
        public Int64 ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Doctor> doctors { get; set; }
        //And some others
    }
```

When a Doctor want to sign up  in this system , He/She just can registers one clinic and after Signing , He/She can registers another clinic.I need update this relation.When a doctor want to register her/his new clinic , I get her/his signup information in `DTO` classes , Add new `clinic` information (in  `ClinicDto` class form) to `Doctor.Clinics` collections and try to update Doctor in databas by ID Like this :

for example This is information that i get from database :

```
Doctor_ID : 1
Clinics : {Clinic_ID : 1}
```

And this is information that i send to database for update Doctor entity :

```
Doctor_ID : 1
Clinics : {Clinic_ID : 1 , Clinic_ID : 2 }
```

This is my update method in Server :

```
[HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Doctor))]
    // PUT: api/Doctors/registerNewClinicForExistingDoctor 
    public IHttpActionResult registerNewClinicForExistingDoctor(Doctor doctor)
    {
        db.doctors.Attach(doctor);
        db.Entry(doctor).Property(x => x.clinics).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(doctor);
    }
```

When I tried to update `Doctor` entity this error occurred.

> The property 'clinics' on type 'Doctor' is not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.

[image]

in this picture you can see Doctor class before updating (in winform).

Now , Please Say me what I have to do when I want to register new Clinic for an existing doctor. And whats wrong ?